# How to search and print text cells from an excel column into a new excel doc?

Tags: python, excel, text

I am currently looking for a way to automate a search for cells containing text in excel using python, then printing to a new excel sheet.

My background in coding is very limited but I have done something similar in Python some odd years ago, finding text matching one cell and printing it to another sheet. However, this requires finding information from several cells at once in a large dataset. From my limited skillset I am unable to tell if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.read_excel` can do this.  Check **pandas** official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)